# Exoplayer - Avoid video stretching

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am using Exoplayer to load videos from the Internet.

When the videos is loaded and starts to display inside the container, the video automatically stretches while the flag `MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT` is set on the video renderer.

```
this._videoRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(this._context, source, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/selfie_slider_slide_thumbnail"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/selfie_slider_slide_video"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The image is correctly displayed, but not the video. Here are two examples to correctly illustrate the problem:

- This is the thumbnail inside the container
  [image: This is the thumbnail inside the container]
- This is the video once it is loaded. You can see that it is stretched (don't pay attention to the black lines, this is a bad cropping)
  [image: This is the video once it is loaded]

I guess I could be resizing the container according to the thumbnail size, but that would mean that I would need to resize the container every time the video changes, so I'm trying to find a better way to do that. If anyone has a guess, I'm taking it!

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the Exoplayer [AspectRatioFrameLayout](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/AspectRatioFrameLayout.java) or in previous version they used a [AspectRatioTextureView](https://github.com/HugoGresse/SimpleExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/io/gresse/hugo/simpleexoplayer/view/AspectRatioTextureView.java). You'll need to receive the `onVideoSizeChanged` event and update the TextureView/FrameLayout ratio :

```
/**
 * @param width                    video width
 * @param height                   video width
 * @param unappliedRotationDegrees ?
 * @param pixelRatio               (optional) pixel ratio
 */
@Override
public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelRatio) {
    if (!mRatioAlreadyCalculated && mVideoWidthHeightRatio != (float) width / height) {
        mVideoWidthHeightRatio = ((float) width / height) * pixelRatio;
        mRatioAlreadyCalculated = true;
    }
    updateVideoRatio();
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps know how to scale-crop it to work like center-crop, but at the top? I've asked about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54216273/878126